# How to make JQuery select individual submenus?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

The Wordpress theme I'm building has a mobile navigation menu, and I've set it up so that a span button appears to the right hand side of every menu item that has children / subpages, as a means of allowing me to open and close the submenus. The only problem is that when I click one of the buttons, all of the submenus open instead of just the one I've clicked. Is there a way of setting the jQuery to single out the individual submenu I'm trying to open?

My jQuery is as follows – I have two scripts, the first one to create the span classes and the second is to make them open the submenus when clicked.

**Script 1:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

$('nav.main-menu#mobile ul li:not(.hide-mobile) ul').parent('li').after('<span class="submenu-button">+</span>');

});
```

**Script 2:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    $('.submenu-button').click(function() {
        $('nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul').toggleClass('open');


    });
});
```

UPDATE –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

**My Header:**

Please note – I've created the menu below via PHP in the Wordpress menus section, so none of my links are hard-coded. Therefore I'd prefer a way of doing this that doesn't involve menu item IDs

```
    <!-- MOBILE NAVIGATION MENU -->
    <div class="mobile-menu">
        <span class="menu-button-close"></span>
        <nav class="main-menu" id="mobile">
            <h6 id="mobile-menu-heading">MENU</h6>
            <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
                <ul id="menu-header-menu-1" class="menu">
                    <li class="hide-desktop menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1386"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-463">
                        <a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/work/">Work</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-584"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/work/landscapes/">Landscapes</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-473"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/work/seascapes/">Seascapes</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-478"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/work/macro/">Macro</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-477"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/work/cities/">Cities</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-475"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/work/long-exposure/">Long Exposure</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-480"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/work/miscellaneous/">Miscellaneous</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item menu-item-10"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/about/">About</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-464"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/shop/">Shop</a></li>
                    <li class="hide-mobile menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-923">
                        <a>Social</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"><a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com/">Facebook</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-924"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/lucie_averill">Instagram</a></li>
                            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-15"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/lucie-averill/">Flickr</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-14"><a href="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/contact/">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

**My PHP**

```
   function register_menus() {

  register_nav_menus(

        array(

            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'theme_wp' ),    
            'header' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
            'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu' )     
    ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_menus' );
```

Comment: Could you include your html?

Comment: Hi, I've added it above. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `$('nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul').toggleClass('open');` is targeting all occurrences of `nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul` and applying the open class. To solve this issue, you'll have to use `this` within the event handler. Something similar to as follows...

```
$('.submenu-button').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});
```

This will target the specific element that is clicked, and move up to its parent element, applying the class directly for this. It would have to be tweaked to your HTML, but the general idea should follow through.

**UPDATE**

For visualization, here's a JSFiddle using the exact HTML.
https://jsfiddle.net/8nj5y4t1/4/

Due to the nature of your HTML, you would have to target it as...

```
$('.submenu-button').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('open');
});
```

This will allow it to lock on to the li, and not the ul which contains all the expandable list items.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this in my script and it doesn't seem to work, when I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: The cause could be in one of two places, Javascript, or CSS. I suggest using the Web Inspector to check whether or not the class `open` is being properly added when the button is clicked. If it is, then the CSS rule which reveals the hidden menu items needs to be reviewed, as the way to select the opened element may have changed. I included a JSFiddle in my answer, reviewing it may offer some answers.

Comment: If the site located in your HTML's menu items is correct, I believe the culprit is that `nav.main-menu#mobile ul li.current-menu-item a:link` has set the color of the menu items to `#ffffff` causing them to appear missing as the background is also white. For me, at least (On Google Chrome) the menu is properly expanding when clicked.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this just now – I've managed to get it to work, so thanks very much the code does work :). I think what threw me is the CSS selector: `.menu-item-has-children:not(.open) .sub-menu {`... is this the same as writing `.menu-item-has-children {` followed by `.menu-item-has-children.open {`? Before I was using `nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul {` and `nav.main-menu#mobile ul ul.open {`and  changing the height to open it, I'm going to try and get this to work now it's not the `ul`I'm adding the `open` class to.

Comment: Yes, your understanding of the `:not` pseudo-class is spot on. It is selective only when a class does not exist on an element, and allows me to declare a single rule, rather than multiple. As for setting the height, I would recommend setting a `max-height` of 0 when it is closed and an unreachable size when it is open, this would allow you to utilize a css transition as it is opening, whereas height would not.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, I think I'm nearly there – I've got this to work with the max-height rules like you suggested. the only issue is that the parent links are hidden as well, when the submenus are closed. Do you know what part of the CSS could be causing this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110321/discussion-between-sidriel-and-jack1991).